# Is it possible to use shadow DOM in a webworker?

Tags: html, web-worker, shadow-dom

I know Webworkers can't manipulate DOM (and that are not supposed to) but I would like to know if there is any way to manipulate a shadow DOM within a webworker (attaching it later in the UI thread). Even if I'm almost sure is not possible, I couldn't find any information/documentation on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot post or transfer a Shadow DOM to a Web Worker for the same reasons you cannot do that with a DOM element.

Instead, you should manipulate HTML as `string` in your worker, then insert it in a Shadow DOM `shadowRoot` via its `innerHTML` property.

Depending of the architecture of your projet, you could also consider using [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebSockets) that can directly interact with the DOM.